# Can I customize the title of the buttons at the Camera Controls with Custom Camera Overlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uipickerviewcontroller

I have a big issue, I'm developing an Application that is in Spanish, so al the labels and controls needs to be in Spanish. The thing is when I pick a Photo from the Camera, the Default Camera Controls comes in english: "Take Photo", "Cancel" and "Retake". My question is if I can customize this buttons to make it appear in Spanish: "Tomar Foto", "Cancelar" y "Volver a tomar".

This is actually my code:

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto :(id)sender
{
    if (fotos.count <= 3) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        }
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;

        // image picker needs a delegate,
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:(id)self];

        // Place image picker on the screen
        if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0)
        {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app is setup to support Spanish localization and the user has set their device to use Spanish, then all buttons and labels of standard controls will also show Spanish.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", @"en", @"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate